# Using php and mongodb, how do you remove a document by type

Tags: php, mongodb

I have read the documentation and searched all over but I can't find how to do it.
If I have a document inside a collection and the document is an empty array I can remove it like this:

```
db.data.remove(array('document'=>array()))
```

or like this:

```
db.data.remove(array('document'=>[]))
```

But if the array is not empty it doesn't work, so I tried like this:

```
db.data.remove(array('document'=>array('$type'=>4)))
```

Am I doing it wrong? Is there any way to do this?
Removing the document on another criteria isn't useful for me.

Comment: @JulianHollmann it doesn;t answer it even though it works with the size criteria. I mentioned I cant use any other criteria.

Comment: If the only criteria you can use is type, you're doing something wrong. There's no way to find out if an array is empty with $type.

Comment: I didn't ask how to find out if the array is empty by using type, I asked how I can remove the document basesd on its type, which is clearly an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Finally I found out what your problem is.

```
// test document
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe1af4dd404b1863ff20aac"), "document" : [ 1 ] }
```

The `$type` operator looks inside the array, not the array itself so the following find returns nothing:

```
db.test.find({document : { $type : 4  } })
```

Now in my testcase the document contains a double, the following find returns the document:

```
db.test.find({document : { $type : 1  } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe1af4dd404b1863ff20aac"), "document" : [ 1 ] }
```

Please see also the bug report about this topic:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1475

Comment: this works but it does not help and it's the exact same syntax as with type, but with type it doesnt work, and the type is a god damn array

Comment: please see my udpated answer.